# How to identify which button is being dragged

Tags: android

Am new to Drag and drop in android and I have three buttons and i want to know which button is being dragged because I want to do different tasks on each one of them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity must be declared like

```
YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener
```

You declare buttons and set tags on them in oncreate as

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
         button.setTag("1");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
            }
        });
}
```

In the onTouch function you can get the tag of the view which is touched

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
Log.d("TAG",view.getTag());
```

so you will know which button is dragged